# During send email using gmail in Symfony2 error occured

Tags: symfony, gmail, mailer

I have problem to send email using gmail. When I tested form on my server mailer works ok but after moved website to another provider error ocured

```
INFO - Matched route "my_frontend_default_index" (parameters: "_controller": "My\FrontendBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction", "_route": "my_frontend_default_index")
ERROR - Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "tomasz.zalewski01@gmail.com" using 1 possible authenticators
```

my parameters.yml

```
parameters:
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_auth_mode: login
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: 'tomasz.zalewski01@gmail.com'
```

my config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
   transport: gmail
   host:      smtp.gmail.com
   username:  'tomasz.zalewski01@gmail.com'
   password:  'password'
```

Someone have idea where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all why are you not using your parameter keys in your config? You shouldnt need to touch the config at all. Leave it as:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:  %mailer_transport%
    host:       %mailer_host%
    username:   %mailer_user%
    password:   %mailer_password%
    port:       %mailer_port%
    encryption: %mailer_encrypt%
```

Then for your parameters.yml use:

```
parameters:
    # ...
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host:      ~
    mailer_user:      your_gmail_username
    mailer_password:  your_gmail_password
    mailer_port:      465
```

As suggested in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html

Comment: Using stis setting I recieve error: ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "mailer_port". Did you mean this: "mailer_host"?

Comment: You can add the mailer_port to your parameters file then, What version of symfony and swiftmailer are you using?

Comment: I visited [http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha](http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) and after this mailer sends emails

Comment: @Tomasz edit your question with this response http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha because it resolved my problem also.